# Creating a toplist with MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, join, union

I would like to find out who has the most amount of profit based upon an transaction table. (a toplist)

```
Table: Transactions

    +--------------+
    | id           |
    +--------------+
    | buy_user_id  |
    +--------------+
    | sell_user_id |
    +--------------+
    | amount       |
    +--------------+
    | price        |
    +--------------+
```

This table holds information about transactions which occurred durning an exchange between two individuals. 
"buy_user_id" is the buyer while "sell_user_id" is the seller.

"amount" is how many stocks was bought, price is at what price (in USD). The turnover is then (amount*price).

I would like to figure out which users had the most profit. If you take the total profit minus the total losses, the end result should be 0.

e.g.:

```
    +---+---------+--------+
    | # | User ID | Profit |
    +---+---------+--------+
    | 1 | 13      | +1200  |
    +---+---------+--------+
    | 2 | 52      | +300   |
    +---+---------+--------+
    | 3 | 29      | -500   |
    +---+---------+--------+
    | 4 | 72      | -1000  |
    +---+---------+--------+
```

Suggestions?

**Here is a full example, with transaction table first:**

```
    +----+-------------+--------------+--------+-------+
    | id | buy_user_id | sell_user_id | amount | price |
    +----+-------------+--------------+--------+-------+ 
    | 1  | 13          | 72           | 1000   | 0.01  | $10 paid by 13 for 1000 stocks   (now 13 has $10 loss while 72 has $10 profit)
    +----+-------------+--------------+--------+-------+
    | 2  | 72          | 13           | 1000   | 1.01  | $1010 paid by 72 for 1000 stocks (now 72 has $1000 loss while 13 has $1000 profit)
    +----+-------------+--------------+--------+-------+
    | 3  | 13          | 72           | 500    | 0.02  | $10 paid by 13 for 500 stocks    (now 72 has $990 loss while 13 has $990 profit)
    +----+-------------+--------------+--------+-------+
    | 4  | 72          | 13           | 100    | 5.10  | $510 paid by 72 for 100 stocks   (now 72 has $1500 loss while 13 has $1500 profit)
    +----+-------------+--------------+--------+-------+
    | 5  | 29          | 13           | 400    | 1.25  | $500 paid by 29 for 400 stocks   (now 29 has $500 loss while 13 has $2000 profit)
```

this example should generate this result:

```
    +---+---------+--------+
    | # | User ID | Profit |
    +---+---------+--------+
    | 1 | 13      | +2000  |
    +---+---------+--------+
    | 2 | 72      | -1500  |
    +---+---------+--------+
    | 3 | 29      | -500   |
    +---+---------+--------+
```

What would be the best way to accomplish this? And is this making sense?

My attempt:

```
SELECT sell_user_id as user_id, SUM(amount*price) as amount, 'sell' as type 
FROM exchange_transactions 
GROUP BY sell_user_id 
UNION 
SELECT buy_user_id as user_id, SUM(amount*price) as amount, 'buy' as type 
FROM exchange_transactions 
GROUP BY buy_user_id
```

Comment: So, what have you tried? This is not very simple but not very difficult either. You'll need to use `GROUP BY` and an aggregate function: `SUM()`,

Comment: Well I tried many things... this is close, but I'm not sure how to complete it: SELECT sell_user_id as user_id, SUM(amount*price) as amount, 'sell' as type FROM `transactions` GROUP BY sell_user_id
UNION
SELECT buy_user_id as user_id, SUM(amount*price) as amount, 'buy' as type FROM `transactions` GROUP BY buy_user_id

Comment: What is `pair_id`? It's not in the table definition.

Comment: don't mind the pair_id, it's not relevant (i removed it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT user_id
     , SUM(profit) AS profit
     , SUM(stock_balance) AS stock_balance
FROM
    ( SELECT sell_user_id AS user_id
           , +SUM(amount*price) AS profit
           , -SUM(amount) AS stock_balance
      FROM exchange_transactions 
      GROUP BY sell_user_id
    UNION ALL
      SELECT buy_user_id
          , -SUM(amount*price)
          , +SUM(amount) 
      FROM exchange_transactions 
      GROUP BY buy_user_id
    ) AS tmp
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY profit DESC
```

Comment: Thank you, this does exactly what I was trying to do, but what is the deal with stock_balance? It showed up as 0 on all users.

Comment: It counts how many stocks they bought minus how many they sold. I thought you might want to know if someone sold more than he bought (from a previous stock he had) or he bought more than sold (so increasing his stock of stocks). And there was an error in that calculation, edited now.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following should help you get closer to what you're looking for:

```
SELECT USER_ID, SUM(AMOUNT) AS PROFIT_LOSS FROM
(SELECT sell_user_id as user_id,
   SUM(amount * price) as amount
   FROM exchange_transactions
   GROUP BY sell_user_id
 UNION 
 SELECT buy_user_id as user_id,
   SUM(amount * price * -1) as amount
   FROM exchange_transactions
   GROUP BY buy_user_id)
ORDER BY PROFIT_LOSS DESC;
```

Share and enjoy.

Comment: You miss another `GROUP BY user_id` in the external query.